# Medieval man transported to modern day--surprised by cars but wine hasn't changed

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

The story, which might have been an Outer Limits episode or some other TV show, or a short story, opens with a man from the middle dark ages finding himself walking in the European countryside and suddenly confronted by a metal monster (automobile). He is taken to a home where he is fed and interrogated. He remembers being in his fields and suddenly transported to a modern day countryside. The story ends when he is told nobody can help him see his family again,and he hangs himself. He is awestruck by modern life, but makes a comment saying "at least wine hasn't changed".

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/155106/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please check out [our](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on writing a good story-ID question, and [edit] in any additional details you can remember. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

Comment: One Twilight Zone episode that has some similarities is "A Hundred Yards Over the Rim"? Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Hundred_Yards_Over_the_Rim

Comment: Thanks,that was one of my favorite episodes of TZ,but it isn't what I was after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an episode of not-very-good tv show called Psi Factor. I just dug around and the title of the episode appears to be Man Out of Time: http://www.tvguide.com/tvshows/psi-factor-chronicles-of-the-paranormal/episode-3558581/203892/

Looks like it's up on YouTube. As I said, the series was not great, sort of a facsimile of X-Files. But I agree this episode was somewhat moving.

Comment: That is the story for sure,and I thank you for finding it! I definitely don't remember seeing it as a PSI episode,and I am sure I read the story somewhere. The PSI show credits don't seem to show where the story came from,though. Again,I really appreciate your efforts! Very moving episode!

Comment: Great! Don't forget to click the green checkmark to the left to mark the answer as accepted/the question as solved.